# Does this sentence need a comma?

Tags: punctuation

Does this sentence need a comma?

> Further to your recent phone call I can confirm that we have waived the charge applied to your account after your payment.

Comment: Also, it's not clear, from its placement, how "after your payment" figures into this. After your payment, we have waived the (late?) charge?

Comment: Where are you thinking about putting one?

Comment: I do not think it needs a comma, if you mean after *phone call*. It is legitimate to write longish introductory phrases without using a comma to separate such a phrase from the rest of the sentence. When I have a moment I will try to provide a resource for this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I comma would do well in your sentence:

> Further to your recent phone call, I can confirm that we have waived the charge applied to your account after your payment.

This just allows the reader to get a breath before reading the rest of the sentence.

Comment: "Further to your recent call" sounds very odd if not outright wrong.  At least, to me it does.

Comment: @Kevin [Further to](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/business-english/further-to) is legitimate English. But some constructions used in Business English sound stilted; some are remnants from the 1950s or earlier. The class I took in modern Business Communication advises against using such phrases.

Comment: @δοῦλος Ah, I'm American and this seems to be more common in BE

Comment: ==## @Kevin Dont get me wrong I dont think this sentence is at all gramatically correct in any sense but I was asked to show the OP where to put commas, not how to fix the wording of the sentence ##==

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "further to" is used, especially in BE, to refer to an earlier letter, conversation, call, meeting, etc. in business letters. A comma is always put after the noun that comes after this phrase.

So we must put a comma after the noun "call".